# Scraping with Google Apps Script

Tags: post, authentication, google-apps-script, web-scraping, get

I am trying to get data from a web page.
I need to log in first to get what I need, but I have never been able to succeed in logging in.

URL of the page is 'https://ssl4.bcart.jp/b-gate/login.php'.

This is a log in page, and here is what I write in my code;

```
var url = "https://ssl4.bcart.jp/b-gate/login.php";
var params = {
  method: "GET",
  followRedirects: false
}
var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
Logger.log(content.getContentText());
```

In the log, I get nothing.

I think that I need a token to log into the web page.
According to the source, I need this token:

meta name="csrf-token" content="***********************************"

This token is dynamic and varies in every access.

When I get a token, I have to send the token, userID and password to https://ssl4.bcart.jp/b-gate/login_action.php by Post method.

Is it possible to programmatically log into this page?
If yes, please point out what I am doing it wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: It may not be possible through Google scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Is this because the page is dynamically rendered?

Comment: I agree that this is probably not possible. The CSRF token is not an authentication token, it is unrelated to your case.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I send the credential info directly to https://ssl4.bcart.jp/b-gate/login_action.php and get cookies, then I access other pages with cookies. Is it impossible to get data from the other pages which need login by this way on this site? I'm very new to web scraping. I hope somebody could help :(

Comment: @kurtman Did you ever figure this out? Dealing with the same thing

Comment: @shivavelingker unfortunately, I have never solved this issue and gave up on this. Hope someone else will figure this out.

Comment: @kurtman I found an implementation using Python and then translated that verbatim to JS for App Scripts. The translated version didn't seem to work, I think for the lack of properly maintaining the session. This was a few months ago, so it's been awhile, but I believe that was the issue